# roslaunch use arg to launch serial_node.py

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to roslaunch serial_node.py node with launch file.

I add arg tag in launch file

```
<arg name="_port" default="/dev/ttyACM0" />
<arg name="_baud" default="9600/>"
<node name="serial_node" pkg="rosserial_python" type="serial_node.py" args="$(arg _port) $(arg _baud)"/>
```

But after I roslaunch the launch file, it fails. It seems like the two arg do not work at all

> [ERROR] [WallTime: 1484219964.751265] Error opening serial: could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyUSB0'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251811/roslaunch-use-arg-to-launch-serial_node.py/) by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2017-01-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `serial_node.py` node requires private parameters not command line arguments. You need to be using `<param>` tags instead of the `args` attribute. Check out the [Examples section on the rosserial_python wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_python#Examples) for an example of how to do this.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2017-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2017-01-14**:
Thanks for your help! It really helps!